# I'm running out of room on my root partition. How do I expand it with free space?

Tags: partition, debian

I'm running Debian (wheezy) on my Raspberry Pi, and I apparently allocated something incorrectly when setting it up awhile back. I have a 16GB SD card, and I'm only using a couple GB for the root partition.

When I plug in the card to my Mac card reader, and this is what I see.

[image: Screenshot of partition information]

It looks like I have a large chunk of unused space. How do I go about reclaiming this without wiping out my existing data/settings? Looking for command-line instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `raspi-config` command and select "expand_root fs".